# jquery mmenu reloads page and reopens with wrong width on Android

Tags: jquery, mmenu

I am using the jquery menu 'mmenu', and have a fully finished site, tested and working on IE, Firefox, Android 4.4, iPhone, iPad, etc.

This week I had someone test the site on a device with Android 5.1.1 and they found a huge issue with the menu.

Basically, the menu opens up and loads fine.

They then tap on an arrow to the right of the menu, to open up a sub-menu.

This causes the page to reload, and now the menu is expanded way beyond the visible width of the page, and the user has to drag the screen to the left to see the arrow again. Once they drag the menu all the way off to the left and they can see the arrows, clicking on the arrows then works ok!

I tried adding in the "fullscreen" extension, and this made it worse! The width of the menu after the page reload is now a lot worse, and more dragging to the left is needed to see the arrows again after this page load.

Any ideas??

This is really odd behaviour and is really annoying, as the site was fully finished and ready to go before this issue was spotted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant explain why the menu was showing this odd behaviour, but I have managed to find a workaround that seems to work.

Keeping the main site page fixed and sliding the menu open over the page (rather than sliding the page along with the menu) seems to fix this issue.

This is done by using the following code:

```
offCanvas: {
position  : "left",
zposition : "front"
},
```

The main page is now fixed and doesnt move, and the menu slides open over the page and always shows the correct width.